# Twenty seventeen Menu is not responsive not clickble

Tags: menus, theme-twenty-seventeen

I am customising twentyseventeen theme.There is problem in responsive menu menu is not clickable.here is my code of header.php

```
<?php
/**
* The header for our theme
*
* This is the template that displays all of the <head> section and everything up until <div id="content">
*
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/#template-partials
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
* @since 1.0
* @version 1.0
*/

?><!DOCTYPE html>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js no-svg">
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<link href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>//assets/css/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>//assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>//assets/js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>//assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js">
</script>
 <script>
         $(function() {
            $( "#accordion-1" ).accordion();
         });
      </script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
                    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                        $('.nav-menu li.menu-item a').addClass('hvr-underline-from-left');
                        $('.nav-menu').addClass('group');
                        $('.nav-menu').attr('id', 'example-one');
                        $('.nav-menu').parent('div').addClass('nav-wrap');
                    });
                </script>
 <style>
   #accordion-1{font-size: 14px;} </style>
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    img.wp-smiley,
    img.emoji {
    display: inline !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    height: 1em !important;
    width: 1em !important;
    margin: 0 .07em !important;
    vertical-align: -0.1em !important;
    background: none !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    }
</style>
<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.3.2/release/featherlight.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" title="Featherlight Styles" />
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.3.2/release/featherlight.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="contact-form-7-css" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="twentyseventeen-fonts-css" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/css/css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="genericons-css" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/css/genericons.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="twentyseventeen-style-css" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css-css" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="camera-css" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/css/camera.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="custom-css" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/css/custom.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" id="responsive-css" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/css/responsive.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/theme.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/custom.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" id="accordion" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/css/accodian.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 4.2.17">

<style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>

                        <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        /*jQuery('#camera_wrap_4').camera({
         height: 'auto',
         loader: 'bar',
         fx:'simpleFade',
         pagination: false,
         thumbnails: true,
         hover: false,
         opacityOnGrid: false,
         imagePath: '../images/'
         });

         jQuery('.link-img').on('click', function() {
         var pic_src = jQuery(this).data('src');
         jQuery('#slide1').attr("data-src", pic_src);
         })*/

       /* $.backstretch([
            "http://localhost/mimshach/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/1st_Picture.jpg"
                    , "http://localhost/mimshach/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/2nd-Picture.jpg"
                    , "http://localhost/mimshach/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/3rd-Picture.jpg"
        ], {duration: 30000, fade: 750});*/

        // Get the number of banner images on the page
        var numberImages = $('#nv-featurecarousel img.nv-imgbnr-bg').length;
        var time = 30;
        var method = 'fadeAndRotate';
        // if there is only one image loaded in the carousel the rotation
        // and sliding functions are not required

        /* if (numberImages > 1) {
         nvs.featurecarousel.start(numberImages, time, method);
         }
         $('#nv-carousel img').css('height', $(window).height());
         $(window).resize(function(){
         $('#nv-carousel img').css('height', $(window).height());
         });*/

    });
</script>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Get the number of banner images on the page
    var numberImages = $('#nv-featurecarousel img.nv-imgbnr-bg').length;
    var time = 30;
    var method = 'fadeAndRotate';
    // if there is only one image loaded in the carousel the rotation
    // and sliding functions are not required
    if (numberImages > 1) {
    nvs.featurecarousel.start(numberImages, time, method);
    }
    $('#nv-carousel img').css('height', $(window).height());
    $(window).resize(function(){
    $('#nv-carousel img').css('height', $(window).height());
    });

    });
    </script>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/jquery.form.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var _wpcf7 = {"loaderUrl":"http:\/\/newtestserver.com\/dev\/mimshach\/wp-content\/plugins\/contact-form-7\/images\/ajax-loader.gif","sending":"Sending ..."};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/masonry.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/functions.js"></script> 
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php //echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/navigation.js"></script> -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/jquery.mobile.customized.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php //echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ); ?>/assets/js/example.js"></script> -->

</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <div id="page" class="site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'twentyseventeen' ); ?></a>
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
         <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="top-header clearfix">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="logo">
                                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/header/header', 'image' ); ?>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                 <div class="col-sm-9">
                    <div class="top-nav clearfix">
                        <?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu'=> 'topbar' ) ); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="top-search clearfix">
                        <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-2') ) : ?>
                         <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
             </div>
         </div>

        <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'top' ) ) : ?>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar">
            <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <div class="nav-wrap">
                <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/navigation/navigation', 'top' ); ?>

            </div><!-- .wrap -->
             </nav>
        </div>
            <!-- .navigation-top -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </header>
<?php
    /*
     * If a regular post or page, and not the front page, show the featured image.
     * Using get_queried_object_id() here since the $post global may not be set before a call to the_post().
     */
    if ( ( is_single() || ( is_page() && ! twentyseventeen_is_frontpage() ) ) && has_post_thumbnail( get_queried_object_id() ) ) :
        echo '<div class="single-featured-image-header">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( get_queried_object_id(), 'twentyseventeen-featured-image' );
        echo '</div><!-- .single-featured-image-header -->';
    endif;
    ?>
    <div class="site-content-contain">
       <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

This is my functions.js

/**
     * Functionality specific to Twenty Seventeen.
     *
     * Provides helper functions to enhance the theme experience.
     */

```
( function( $ ) {
    var body    = $( 'body' ),
        _window = $( window ),
        nav, button, menu;

    nav = $( '#site-navigation' );
    button = nav.find( '.menu-toggle' );
    menu = nav.find( '.nav-menu' );

    /**
     * Adds a top margin to the footer if the sidebar widget area is higher
     * than the rest of the page, to help the footer always visually clear
     * the sidebar.
     */
    $( function() {
        if ( body.is( '.sidebar' ) ) {
            var sidebar   = $( '#secondary .widget-area' ),
                secondary = ( 0 === sidebar.length ) ? -40 : sidebar.height(),
                margin    = $( '#tertiary .widget-area' ).height() - $( '#content' ).height() - secondary;

            if ( margin > 0 && _window.innerWidth() > 999 ) {
                $( '#colophon' ).css( 'margin-top', margin + 'px' );
            }
        }
    } );

    /**
     * Enables menu toggle for small screens.
     */
    ( function() {
        if ( ! nav || ! button ) {
            return;
        }

        // Hide button if menu is missing or empty.
        if ( ! menu || ! menu.children().length ) {
            button.hide();
            return;
        }

        button.on( 'click.twentyseventeen', function() {
            nav.toggleClass( 'toggled-on' );
            if ( nav.hasClass( 'toggled-on' ) ) {
                $( this ).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
                menu.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'true' );
            } else {
                $( this ).attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
                menu.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
            }
        } );

        // Fix sub-menus for touch devices.
        if ( 'ontouchstart' in window ) {
            menu.find( '.menu-item-has-children > a, .page_item_has_children > a' ).on( 'touchstart.twentyseventeen', function( e ) {
                var el = $( this ).parent( 'li' );

                if ( ! el.hasClass( 'focus' ) ) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    el.toggleClass( 'focus' );
                    el.siblings( '.focus' ).removeClass( 'focus' );
                }
            } );
        }

        // Better focus for hidden submenu items for accessibility.
        menu.find( 'a' ).on( 'focus.twentyseventeen blur.twentyseventeen', function() {
            $( this ).parents( '.menu-item, .page_item' ).toggleClass( 'focus' );
        } );
    } )();

    /**
     * @summary Add or remove ARIA attributes.
     * Uses jQuery's width() function to determine the size of the window and add
     * the default ARIA attributes for the menu toggle if it's visible.
     * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.5
     */
    function onResizeARIA() {
        if ( 643 > _window.width() ) {
            button.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
            menu.attr( 'aria-expanded', 'false' );
            button.attr( 'aria-controls', 'primary-menu' );
        } else {
            button.removeAttr( 'aria-expanded' );
            menu.removeAttr( 'aria-expanded' );
            button.removeAttr( 'aria-controls' );
        }
    }

    _window
        .on( 'load.twentyseventeen', onResizeARIA )
        .on( 'resize.twentyseventeen', function() {
            onResizeARIA();
    } );

    /**
     * Makes "skip to content" link work correctly in IE9 and Chrome for better
     * accessibility.
     *
     * @link http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/01/15/fixing-skip-to-content-links/
     */
    _window.on( 'hashchange.twentyseventeen', function() {
        var element = document.getElementById( location.hash.substring( 1 ) );

        if ( element ) {
            if ( ! /^(?:a|select|input|button|textarea)$/i.test( element.tagName ) ) {
                element.tabIndex = -1;
            }

            element.focus();
        }
    } );

    /**
     * Arranges footer widgets vertically.
     */
    if ( $.isFunction( $.fn.masonry ) ) {
        var columnWidth = body.is( '.sidebar' ) ? 228 : 245;

        $( '#secondary .widget-area' ).masonry( {
            itemSelector: '.widget',
            columnWidth: columnWidth,
            gutterWidth: 20,
            isRTL: body.is( '.rtl' )
        } );
    }
} )( jQuery );
```

I Cannot get Why responsive menu is not  open.please help me with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line in you code `button.on( 'click.twentyseventeen', function() {` should that just be:

`button.on( 'click', function() {`

the `.twentyseventeen` is appended to a few event names. I'm not positive this is necessary. Can you verify?

Comment: Still is not working @signal2013 :(

Comment: Normally, things like this can be debugged using the Web Browser's inspection tools. Like, CTRL-SHIFT-i in Chrome. Check the console for any errors on click, or add breakpoints and then step through the code. If you want, you can add a link to your site, it would be easier to debug the live version. Or paste the rendered copy of the HTML output here to review (NB: delete any private data if necessary)

Comment: The 'click.twentyseventeen' syntax is for a namespaced click handler, which allows it to be referenced more easily in other code. That alone should not be the source of the menu problem, except if some other Javascript is doing button.off('click.twentyseventeen', function...)

Comment: Sorry i forgot to give answer. I have disable footer so my scripts was not running Thanks for help.